# How can i add two columns from sql to listview?

Tags: android, xamarin

i'm using this code:

```
  var listview1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.InventoryList);
  var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<object>(this,  Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
  listview1.Adapter = adapter;

  con.Open();

  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,Code from Inventory", con);

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            adapter.Add((string)sqlReader["Name"+"Code"]);

        }
        sqlReader.Close();
        con.Close();
```

I'm getting an error:System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sqlReader is a map, you should do something like:

```
 adapter.Add(sqlReader["Name"].ToString() + " - " + sqlReader["Code"].ToString());
```

You can't concatenate two keys (sqlReader["Name"+"Code"]) and expect two concatenated values to be returned.

Comment: Thank you bro so fast and worked answer! What if i want an enter to each of my colums?

Comment: Solved System.Environment.NewLine,Thank you again